# Web page scraping with WebBrowser control: compensating for javascript error that disables needed script in target page

Tags: javascript, .net, webbrowser-control

My question is *not* about how to suppress Javascript errors. It's a bit weirder than that.

I am trying to write a screen scraper in C#, using [WebBrowserWaiter](https://github.com/LeastOne/WebBrowserWaiter) as an optionally-headless browser. The page I am scraping is not under my control in any way, nor do I have access to its source or developers.

When I run the app, a Javascript pop-up appears, reporting that one linked script has an undefined variable. I've downloaded and dug into the (minified) script, and, while I don't know what it's doing, I could see that, yep, it was referring to a variable (call it `InfoIcon`) that wasn't defined.

This matters, because the data I need isn't in the page when I subsequently scrape it: I infer that this script, or at least some part of it, is part of what puts the data on the screen!

My question, then, is:

Is there any way my scraper can compensate for the page being scraped having a Javascript syntax error, that *only* appears in the WebBrowser, and disables functionality I need to have run?

I am aware that I could copy the offending script, fix the error, and paste it (programmatically) into the page, but I am vague on how to ensure my version of the script and all its functions replaces the offending one. Remember, it's been minified and it's *very* long.

Comment: What does `sessionStorage.getItem("IE-NOTIFY")` return for your headless browser? Where is the value set?

Comment: Weirdly, it appears to be in code later in the same function that does the `getItem`.